# AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.utils' has no attribute 'convert_exception'

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake

Hi i have an issue with deltalake im trying to import
`from delta import *`
but i got the following error
anyone has any idea how to solve it please share it thanks in advance

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/delta/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from delta.tables import DeltaTable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/delta/tables.py", line 17, in <module>
    import delta.exceptions  # noqa: F401; pylint: disable=unused-variable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/delta/exceptions.py", line 152, in <module>
    _patch_convert_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/delta/exceptions.py", line 140, in _patch_convert_exception
    convert_sql_exception = utils.convert_exception
AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.utils' has no attribute 'convert_exception'
>>> from delta import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/delta/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from delta.tables import DeltaTable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/delta/tables.py", line 17, in <module>
    import delta.exceptions  # noqa: F401; pylint: disable=unused-variable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/delta/exceptions.py", line 152, in <module>
    _patch_convert_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/delta/exceptions.py", line 140, in _patch_convert_exception
    convert_sql_exception = utils.convert_exception
AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.utils' has no attribute 'convert_exception'
```

Comment: what is the Spark  version & what is the Delta version?

Comment: delta-core_2.12, Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.1.2
      /_/
                        
Using Scala version 2.12.10, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_302
Branch HEAD
es python Using Python version 3.6.14 (default, Jun 28 2021 21:29:51)

Comment: delta-core 1.0.0 Scala 2.12?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: show how do you start pyspark. Have you installed pyspark via pip or downloaded spark distribution? it works just fine for me.

Comment: it works correctly inside spark container the problem comes when i call the .py using sparksubmitoperator using airflow

Comment: How do you register the jar?

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: This problem continues to surface with `delta-spark-3.1.0` / `pyspark-3.5.0`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same the issue in Glue jupyter notebook. Then I added following before I start the session:

```
%glue_version 3.0 %additional_python_modules graphframes==0.6
%extra_jars s3://s3-path/graphframes.jar,s3://s3-path/delta-core_2.12-1.0.0.jar
%extra_py_files s3://s3-path/graphframes.jar,s3://s3-path/delta-core_2.12-1.0.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I used the delta version 0.6.0 and work!!!